# Assembly, Reserving Space with resq in YASM

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x86-64, yasm

Using YASM I have tried to reserve space for 2000 quadwords, but when I
do this I get a SIGSEGV when I try to write into the reserved block of quadwords.
If I reserve space for only 300 quadwords, the program runs without error.
What causes this?

```
; Using Windows 7 (Intel Celeron 64-bits)
; yasm -f win64 -l forth.lst forth.asm
; gcc -o forth forth.obj

segment .data
controlstr db "%x", 13, 10, 0

segment .bss
dictionaryspace resq 2000
datastackspace  resq 300
databottom  dq 0
returnstackspace resq 300
returnbottom dq 0

segment .text
global main
extern printf

main:
push rbp                ; setup stack frame
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 32             ; reserve space

lea r15, [databottom]   ; initialize data stack pointer
sub r15, 8              ; point to the last word in data stack

mov rax, 666
mov [r15], rax          ; SIGSEGV happens here.

mov rdx, [r15]
lea rcx, [controlstr]
call printf

leave
ret

; End of code.
```

Comment: unrelated: `lea r15, [databottom-8]` should be equivalent and shorter.  Does `default rel` make any difference?  Using LEA with an absolute `[disp32]` addressing mode should work.  BTW, if you're on Windows, you don't *literally* get SIGSEGV do you?  I thought Windows didn't use POSIX signals, unless you're using the Linux subsystem for Windows, but you're using `-fwin64` not `elf64`.

Comment: Also, if you don't need the value in a register, you can `mov qword [r15], 666`.

Comment: Why are you using `dq 0` instead of `resq 1`?  And if you just want a label past the end of `datastackspace`, use `databottom:` on a line by itself.  (Labels are zero-width).  You should always use `:` after label names in NASM syntax, to avoid ambiguity with instruction mnemonics.  Anyway, I don't see any reason why your code would fault on the store; so presumably the problem is specific to Windows or something about your build environment.  It runs fine on Linux (modulo calling-convention arg-passing register differences.)

Comment: What development environment on Windows are you using? Msys? Msys2? Cygwin? something else?

Comment: Works fine with mingw and wine.

Comment: I am using mingw.  Maybe I should try a different version of gcc/yasm.